# Sharepoint javascript list form validation on presaveaction

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a Function named "ViewItem" that calls 2 more functions: "success" and "failed". When "success" is called it goes and check if a value exists and return true if the value exists or false if the value doesnt exist. Lastly I have a 4th function called "PresaveAction" what this function does is check if a value is "yes" or "no", if "no" it returns true and allows me to save and what I want to achieve is if the value is "yes" call the "success" function from before and depending if "success" returns true or false allow me to save. So how do I pass to the PreSaveAction function what "success" return?

```js
function ViewItem()
{

var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('demoTrainingRoom2');
var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
allItems = list.getItems(query);
context.load(allItems, 'Include(Title, EventDate, time2)');

context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.success), Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));
}



function success() {
 
var currentTitle = SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('EventDate').GetValue(); 
for(var i = 0; i < this.allItems.get_count(); i++){
      var item = this.allItems.get_item(i);
      console.log(item.get_item('time2') + ' - ' + currentTitle );
                           
                     if (currentTitle == item.get_item('time2')){
                     alert('There is an event with the same Start Date on DemoTrainingRoom2' + ' ' + item.get_item('time2') + ' - ' + currentTitle );
                     
                       
                      return true; // or item
                       
                                                             
          }
      }

      
                  return false;
    }
    
function failed(sender, args) {
alert("failed. Message:" + args.get_message());
}


function PreSaveAction()    {



var time = SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('EventDate').GetValue();
alert(time + " Current Start Time");
  
if(SPUtility.GetSPField('demoField').GetValue() == "no")
{
     
     alert('No need for validation');
     return true; // save file
    }
    

    else
{
   
 alert('Need to validate date');
     
    //here is where i need to call the result from success 
  
 return false; // don't save file
 }
 
}
```

@Thriggle are you suggestion something like this

```js
var result; //global variable

function ViewItem()
{

var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('demoTrainingRoom2');
var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
allItems = list.getItems(query);
context.load(allItems, 'Include(Title, EventDate, time2)');

context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.success), Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));
}



function success() {
 
var currentTitle = SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('EventDate').GetValue(); 
for(var i = 0; i < this.allItems.get_count(); i++){
      var item = this.allItems.get_item(i);
      console.log(item.get_item('time2') + ' - ' + currentTitle );
                           
                     if (currentTitle == item.get_item('tiempo2')){
                     alert('There is an event with the same Start Date on DemoTrainingRoom2' + ' ' + item.get_item('time2') + ' - ' + currentTitle );
                     
                      var result = "Yes"; 
                     
                      return true; // or item
                       
                                                             
          }
      }

      var result = "No";
       
      return false;
    }
    
function failed(sender, args) {
alert("failed. Message:" + args.get_message());
}


function PreSaveAction()    {



var time = SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('EventDate').GetValue();
alert(time + " Current Start Time");


if(SPUtility.GetSPField('demoField').GetValue() == "no")
{
     
     alert('No need for validation');
     return true;
    }
    

   else if(SPUtility.GetSPField('demoField').GetValue() == "yes" && result == "Yes") 
   {
  alert(result);
  //return false;
} 

else if(SPUtility.GetSPField('demoField').GetValue() == "yes" && result == "No") 
   {
  alert(result);
  //return false;
} 


}
```

Comment: The callback functions that you pass into `context.executeQueryAsync()` will run asynchronously, so your code won't pause execution and wait for the return values of those functions; I don't think there's any way to actually get the return values from those functions when they execute. The next best thing would be to save the values off into global variables that you can then check when `PreSaveAction()` executes.

Comment: @Thriggle thnx for the interest would you mind to show me how?. I dont know how to format code in comments but ill update de question with what i get from what you said

Comment: Yes, what you updated is similar to what I suggested, but instead of `var result = ...` try `this.result = ...`, inside your success function. When you use the `var` keyword, JavaScript creates a new local variable at the current scope. You'll also need to be sure your `ViewItem()` function runs at some time prior to when the user tries to save the form, to be sure your `result` variable has a value by that point. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i did it

```js
var originalSaveButtonClickHandler = function(){};

$(document).ready(function () {
var saveButton = $("[name$='diidIOSaveItem']") //gets form save button and ribbon save button
  if (saveButton.length > 0) {
    originalSaveButtonClickHandler = saveButton[0].onclick;  //save original function
  }
  $(saveButton).attr("onclick", "PreSaveAction2()"); //change   });
});
 //override the default PreSaveAction
 
 //custom PreSaveAction
 function PreSaveAction2(callback) {
  alert("iniciando validacion");
  var time = SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('EventDate').GetValue(); 
  if(SPUtility.GetSPField('demoField').GetValue() == "no") {
   alert('No need for validation');
   originalSaveButtonClickHandler();
   //return true;
  } 
  else if(SPUtility.GetSPField('demoField').GetValue() == "yes") {
  
   var resultado1 = ViewItem('demoTrainingRoom2').then(
     function(allItems) {
      var currentTitle = SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('EventDate').GetValue();
      var res = "No";
      for (var i = 0; i < allItems.get_count(); i++) {
       var item = allItems.get_item(i);
       console.log(item.get_item('tiempo2') + ' - ' + currentTitle );
       if (currentTitle == item.get_item('tiempo2')){
        res = "Si"; 
        console.log('There is an event with the same Start Date on DemoTrainingRoom2' 
         + ' ' + item.get_item('tiempo2') + ' - ' + currentTitle);
             }
      }
      if (res == "Si") {
       alert(res + " there's an event on room 2");
       //return false;
      } else {
       alert(res + " no event on 2");
       originalSaveButtonClickHandler();
       //return true;
      } 
     },
     function (sender, args) {
      alert("failed. Message:" + args.get_message());
     }
   );
   
  }    
 }

 function ViewItem(listTitle) {

  var deferred = $.Deferred();

  var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var web = context.get_web();
  var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
  var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
  var allItems = list.getItems(query);
  context.load(allItems, 'Include(Title, EventDate, tiempo2)');
  context.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, 
     function () { deferred.resolve(allItems); } ),
    Function.createDelegate(this,
     function (sender, args) { deferred.reject(sender, args); }));
 
  return deferred.promise();
 }
```